# How to take out multiple data sets from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I was using Postgresql for my db activities. Now a requirement has come up to use MySQL. we were primarily using Postgresql becuase of the ROW_TO_JSON capability it has.

My doubt here is is it possible for me to pass the data of multiple columns into another single variable which is being used as part of query and convert the same into json?

E.g. in postgresql we have the below.

```
select table1.name, table1.desc properties.properties as properties left join
(SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t) AS properties FROM(SELECT table2.desc AS description,table2.start AS start, table2.end AS end) from table2, table1);
```

any idea if we have similiar kind of functionality in mysql?

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: The SQL you show is invalid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: In MySQL 5.7+, you should be able to produce JSON objects with `JSON_OBJECT()`, key-by-key. So -- in theory, if you know all its columns --, you could use `JSON_OBJECT('col1', col1, 'col2', col2, ...)`. But there is nothing as straightforward as `ROW_TO_JSON()` in PostgreSQL.